# data is getting diisplayed twice in list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-hooks, react-select

I am getting data in the below format.

```
[
  {
    "country_id": 1,
    "country_name": "INDIA",
    "insurance_id": {
      "insurance_id": 1,
      "insurance_name": "LIC",
      "createdAt": "2022-04-07T07:33:34.929Z",
      "modifiedAt": "2022-04-07T07:33:34.929Z",
      "deletedAt": null
    }
  },
  {
    "country_id": 2,
    "country_name": "INDIA",
    "insurance_id": {
      "insurance_id": 101,
      "insurance_name": "HDFC",
      "createdAt": "2022-04-07T07:33:09.698Z",
      "modifiedAt": "2022-04-07T07:33:09.698Z",
      "deletedAt": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "7e71625d-cf8e-4793-ba15-2d84338fde13",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-07T11:13:30.452Z",
    "modifiedAt": "2022-04-07T11:13:30.452Z",
    "deletedAt": null,
    "country_id": 3,
    "country_name": "PAKISTAN",
    "insurance_id": null
  }
  }
]
```

I need to display `country_name` in the list. this value is `duplicate` in above data so it is coming `twice`. I need to display only one time in list.

[image]

below is my code.

```
const [countryName, setCountryName]=useState([]);
const fetchCountry = async ()=>{
        const {data}= await httpClient.get( config.resourceServerUrl+"/country");
        data.length>0? setCountryName(data): setCountryName([]);
     }
```

I am using react-select component to display list.

```
<Select
      id="country" 
      name="contry"   
      placeholder="Select the Country"
      className="align-items-center justify-content-center"
      options={countryName.map((country:Country)=>
             ({ label: country.country_name, value: country.id })
     )}
     onChange={selectInsurer}
  />
```

how can I make this list unique?

Comment: India is in the data twice ... computer languages are basically dumb, they do exactly what you tell them to do, there's no "oh, wait, I already have that one so lets not do that again" - besides, the list IS unique ... the country_id is, anyway

Comment: Make your own unique custom country array list based on country names. And then render that list.

Comment: of course, the issue is that the two India's have different country_id - that would suggest an issue with the source of the data - where is the data coming from? is it something you wrote?

Comment: thank you. is there anyway I can customize the same in react in UI? I can fetch unique data from backend but I am accessing all data at once to use of other data as well.

Comment: `setCountryName([...new Set(data.map(({country_name})=>({country_name})))])`

Comment: @Bravo  Yes, I wrote the same. the data wil be duplicate because same country can have 2 insurance companies so countryname will be duplicate. should I call API twice once for unique record and once for all data? is it advisable?

Comment: @ShrutiSharma - you didn't write the same, because there will be no duplicates - by the way, I'd use `({ label: country.country_name, value: country.country_name })` for the select - since one country can have more than one id and in fact, for `India` it can have NO `.id` at all

Comment: sorry, typo `setCountryName([...new Set(data.map(({country_name})=>country_name))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preprocess your list before giving it to the Select component, like this:

```
const uniqueCountries = [];
for(let country of countryName){
   if(!uniqueCountries.find(c => c.country_name === country.country_name)){
      uniqueCountries.push(country);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list with all the values from your file, even the duplicate ones, then you can refer to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates) question and the accepted answer, it shows you how to create a unique list from a list with duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new list containing only distinct country names, like this:

```
const countries = new Set()
obj.forEach(country => countries.add(country.country_name))
const list = Array.from(countries) // pass this array as options prop
```